# Unlocking Locked Out accounts using PowerShell (not with Quest AD cmdlets)

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windowsdomainaccount

I'm writing a GUI tool using PowerShell that is able to do most AD related tasks with just a user name and button click. I've done all the usual ones (Create / Remove Users, Create / Remove Security & Distribution Groups, Resetting Passwords, etc) but can't find away of unlocking a "Locked Out" account.

I'm trying to do this without using Quest AD cmdlets as I want a more stand alone solution. So I'm wondering whether is possible with plain PowerShell (1.0 or 2.0) in a Windows 2003 Domain.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the lockoutTime property of the DirectoryEntry to 0.

Sample:

```
$x = [ADSI]'LDAP://SomeDN'
$x.lockoutTime = 0
$x.CommitChanges()
$x.Close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Been out of the AD world for a few years. I haven't worked with PowerShell at all but does the link below offer what you're looking for?

http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2007/08/14/enable-disable-unlock-user-accounts/

Comment: That's using the Quest AD cmdlets

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeff, but Barrett is correct. That's using the Quest cmdlets that I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks for your response tho!