# PowerShell Checking locked user in ActiveDirectory

Tags: powershell

Do you know if possible and how I can check if a user is locked in ActiveDirectory without installing the ActiveDirectory module? There is a constraint of installing things on a machine and I was wondering if another function can be use for this, different than Get-ADUser.
Thank you!

Comment: Use the ADSI provider. Not a duplicate but a reference :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585205/unlocking-locked-out-accounts-using-powershell-not-with-quest-ad-cmdlets

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
$sAMAccountName = "testuser"
$ADS_UF_LOCKOUT = 16    
$Attribute = "msds-user-account-control-computed"    
$ADSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$ADSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$ADSearcher.Filter = "samaccountname=$sAMAccountName"
$User = $ADSearcher.FindOne()    
$MyUser = $User.GetDirectoryEntry()
$MyUser.RefreshCache($Attribute)    
$UserAccountFlag = $MyUser.Properties[$Attribute].Value    
if ( $UserAccountFlag -band $ADS_UF_LOCKOUT )
{
Write-host "Account $sAMAccountName is locked"
}
else
{
Write-host "Account $sAMAccountName isn't locked"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at `dsquery`, that is cmd but can be called from Powershell https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732952.aspx

Comment: Thank you a lot! This works for me on some other issues.